# Migrating textFieldConfiguration and maxLengthEnforced to new version of flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, migration

My old code is

```
maxLengthEnforced: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforced,
```

and it gives error

```
Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxLengthEnforced'.
```

Some guids say I shoud replace `maxLengthEnforced` by `maxLengthEnforcement`.
But the new code:

```
maxLengthEnforcement: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforcement,
```

gives new error:

```
The getter 'maxLengthEnforcement' isn't defined for the class 'TextFieldConfiguration<dynamic>'.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/use-maxLengthEnforcement-instead-of-maxLengthEnforced),

> Added a `maxLengthEnforcement` parameter using the new `enum` type
> MaxLengthEnforcement, as a replacement for the now-deprecated boolean
> maxLengthEnforced parameter

Now when it was a boolean, true/false was sufficient in your code, but now it is an `enum` so when you replaced <s>maxLengthEnforced</s> with **maxLengthEnforcement**, you also need to make changes in *textFieldConfiguration* to adjust to this change. Simple replacement will not work, hence the error.

Comment: For a beginner so... what are this "changes" to have same result as old code but by new syntax? @BlazingRSj

Comment: @moshtaba [Default values of maxLengthEnforcement](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/use-maxLengthEnforcement-instead-of-maxLengthEnforced#default-values-of-maxlengthenforcement)